# how to convert int into string in forloop

Tags: android

I want to print json array utrition arrray in textview dynamically problem is that if  I write"1"  in this line  (school3.getJSONObject("1"));
then its print only  first "name" and "Qty" from json. I want to write  j at this line but problem is it shows  error  The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)

```
  for (int j = 1

 school3.getJSONObject(j)
```

is there any method convert int  j= string then add in 
               school3.getJSONObject(j)       like this way

```
     //for example
     string z;
     z=j.tostring();
     school3.getJSONObject(z);

    {
  "status":1,
  "data"
   ,
    "dish_nutrition":
   {
  "1":
  {
     "name":"Cholesterol and Diet",
   "qty":"2"
  },
  "2":
  {
   "name":"Cholesterol and Diet",
  "qty":"1"
  }
  }
         }







  JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");
   final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);

            for (int j = 1; j < school3.length(); j++) {

        final View row = createRow (school3.getJSONObject("1"));
                    table.addView(row);

                num=num+1;
            }






              public View createRow(JSONObject item) throws JSONException {
    View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
    ((TextView) 
     row.findViewById(R.id.localTime)).setText(item.getString("name"));
    ((TextView) 
     row.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp)).setText(item.getString("qty"));

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Integer.toString(int) or use int+"" in converts the integer to string like j+""

```
        for (int j = 1; j < school3.length(); j++) {

        final View row = createRow (school3.getJSONObject(j+""));
                table.addView(row);

            num=num+1;
        }
```

OR

```
        for (int j = 1; j < school3.length(); j++) {

        final View row = createRow (school3.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(j)));
                table.addView(row);

            num=num+1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String z = String.valueOf(j); 
school3.getJSONObject('\"' + z + '\"');
```

Comment: i didlike this

    for (int j = 1; j < school3.length(); j++) {

     String s = String.valueOf(j);
         
        
         final View row = createRow (school3.getJSONObject(s));
      table.addView(row);

but the problem is is only print first value of json not seccond

Comment: its not showing nay value if i do this
String z = String.valueOf(j); 
school3.getJSONObject('\"' + z + '\"');

Answer (score 0):

Integer to string? 
Integer.toString(i)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
school3.getJSONObject('\"' + j + '\"');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert int into string just use                                 **String.valueof(int values);**

and if u need to convert string to int use 
**Integer.parseInt(string values);**

Answer (score 0):

Through it is basic java. you should know that.

```
String.valueof(int values) to convert Int to String


Integer.parseInt(string values) to convert String to Int
```